# load balancer health check WCF service

Tags: wcf, load-balancing

How to let the load balancer health check if a WCF SOAP service is up?

My current solution is to ensure that the WCF service has a base address then configure the load balancer to do a HTTP get request on the base address.

Comment: And this is not working?

Comment: It works. Just looking for alternatives or better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the alternative ways is to ad IsAlive (liek Ping) method, but this will let you know service state on the time you call this method, as well.

It (as well as your way) **will not guarantee** you that second after this, your service still available.

May be you can try some endpoint, supported subscription of service failure event handlers?